# WindowsPhone App data connection FAILS in MarketPlace published App but WORKS in Visual Studio development (same XAP)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, marketplace

Tearing my hair out(!)

My last App update has been accepted and released by MarketPlace but the remote server data connection does NOT work/connect from the downloaded App (from MarketPlace).

However, the same App (the accepted XAP) when I'm running it from Visual Studio, using the same remote server address works just fine.

WHY!... Has anyone else ever run into anything like this?

Here's the remote path:
http://www.streamcommunication.com/ZenAwaken/DownloadableCollections.xml

- I can load that to a browser and retrieve the XML
- When I'm in Visual Studio I can connect via that path and retrieve the file and consume the data
- BUT!! The exact same XAP which has been accepted and distributed by Windows Phone marketplace FAILS.

Is it possible that MarketPlace does something (encryption?) to the XAP that would corrupt the path string?

Any thoughts or experiences would be very helpful!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

The best way to verify that the app is actually sending out a request is to use a debugging proxy to check the requests. This is a very simple process. Here are the steps-

1) Download and install Fiddler and set it up to act as a proxy to remote hosts from Tools->Fiddler Options->Connections

2) Download Connectify and run it to setup a wireless hotspot from your laptop

3) Connect your windows phone to this wifi network and set the proxy as (Your Computer Name) and the port as 8888

4) Now run your app and see what request your app is sending out. You can also check what response is being given.

Let us know your results so that we can help you further.